# JavaScript: Выбрать элементы у которых присутствует определенный класс

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выбрать элементы по конкретному классу(.item_checked), если у `div` блока одновременно установлено несколько классов?

```
<div id="id1"> 
    <div class="myclass1 item_checked">1</div>   
    <div class="myclass2 item_checked">2</div> 
    <div class="myclass3 nextclass3 item_checked">3</div> 
    <div class="myclass4 nextclass4 item_checked">4</div> 
    <div class="myclass5 nextclass5">5</div> 
</div>
```

То есть нужно выбрать все блоки у которых присутствует класс `.item_checked`.
При использовании `querySelectorAll` выбирает только единственный, если прописать класс полностью, например:

```
checked_item = document.querySelectorAll('#id1 [class="myclass4 nextclass4 item_checked"]');
```

Как выбрать все на JavaScript без использования Jquery и прочих библиотек?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в использовании неправильного селектора.

В функции *querySelectorAll* поддерживаются css селекторы, в css для указания класса, перед именем используется `.`

Например:  `document.querySelectorAll('.item_checked)`

Кроме того, можно воспользоваться функцией [getElementsbyClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), которая также вернет список элементов с указанным классом

```
document.getElementByClassName('item_checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Это сейчас так шутить принято?

```
var checked_item = document.querySelectorAll('.item_checked');
console.log(checked_item);  // Выводит массив из 4 элементов, как положено.
```

И что вас не устроило?